# Variants of linked collection instances

Tags: collections

I created a space ship turret in a `Collection` in a separate `.blend` file to use in another file. Then I created linked collection instance couple of times in a new file.

Now I would like to customize them a bit - rotate some of the guns on turrets (not whole turrets though, just some of the objects inside collection). And of course make different rotations on different instances.

After googling a bit only thing I found that was useful was using `Object > Relations > Make library override` but while I can rotate objects I want and still have a link, constraints inside collection seem no to trigger.

I also don't want to append whole collections into the file - I'm quite sure I will make some improvements to turret later and I don't want to replace 10 instances with new version.

What are my options? Is there any reasonable way to do it? It seems as kind of a obvious thing to do with collections and I can't anything useful on the topic...

Comment: welp, I thought I have made some breakthrough with that `Make library override` option but after playing the animation it actually makes all turrets behave in same way. sad

Answer (score 3):

I found it! According to docs `library override` doesn't work well with overriding animations. While I didn't actually animate turrets inside their file, I marked some properties (rotations) as properties for animation - that was enough to break the behavior of `library override`.

[image: happy turrets]

Docs:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/library_overrides.html#editing-an-override

Comment: would you mind to give a better explanation on how you create and control those properties? I'm trying to replicate prefab variants in Unity with instance collections in blender but seems to me this is still not possible. For instance if I have a collection with two objects and two empties instancing that same collection, how can I control the visibility of each object differently in each instance collection?

Comment: one sad thing I noticed is that it works only with collections imported from other files, maybe thats your problem

Comment: makes sense, thank you